# I am trying to change MaxFailedAttempts dynamically. How can I change it?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I don't want to add in di start up. I want to add outside the start up and initialize max failed attempts from the identity options. But the value is not changing after execution.

```
public class CustomIdentityOptions : IOptions<Lockout Options>
{
    public Lockout Options Value { get; set; }
}


public void CustomIdentityOptions(int count)
{
    Value = new Lockout Options
                {
                    AllowedForNewUsers = true,
                    DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    MaxFailedAccessAttempts = count
                };
}
```

Comment: What is *"in di start up"*? Do you mean *"inside the start up"*? What is *"in the start up"*? Or something else?